# Socket.io does not work

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've installed socket.io through the "npm install --save socket.io" and tried to use in the following way;

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
var router = express.Router();
var guestbookData = require('./guestbook.json');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(bodyParser());

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// index page 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index', {
        new_title: "Guestbook App",
        new_paragraph: "Official Guestbook app."
    });
});

// socket checks user a user connected or disconnected
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

// JSON 
app.get('/guestbook', function(req, res) {
    var data = require('./guestbook.json');

    var table =
     '<table border="1"> ';
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        table +=
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + data[i].id + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data[i].username + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data[i].country + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data[i].date + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data[i].message + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
    }
    res.send(table);
});

// create the form
app.get('/newmessage', function(req, res){
  var html = '<form action="/newmessage" method="post">' +
               'Username:' +
               '<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="..." />' +
               'Country:' +
               '<input type="text" name="country" placeholder="..." />' +
               'Message:' +
               '<input type="text" name="message" placeholder="..." />' +
               '<br>' +
               '<button type="submit">Submit</button>' +
            '</form>';

  res.send(html);
});

// get the form data
app.post('/newmessage', function(req, res){
  var data = require('./guestbook.json');
  nextid = (data.length + 1);
  console.log(nextid)
  data.push({
  "id": nextid,
  "username" : req.body.username,
  "country" : req.body.country,
  "date" : new Date(),
  "message" : req.body.message
  });


// Convert JSON to string
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

//Write new data to file
fs.writeFile('guestbook.json', jsonString, (err) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Data saved!');
});

res.send("The new data saved to the file.");
});

// declaring static css
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));


app.listen(8080);
console.log('8080 port');
;
```

Then I added the following into my html file's header part;

```
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
      <script>
        var socket = io();
      </script>
```

However, when I start the application and reload the web page, socket.io does not print 'a user connected' to the console. My console doesn't show any sign of error and the website works normal, so I have truly no idea what is wrong.

I'd be grateful if you can help me.

Comment: you should connect to your server in `io()`

Comment: EDIT: [not applicable] on client `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:<port>')` - like Edgar is saying

Comment: Don't see code that starts the server.  Also, don't see any routes that load the page you're in.  You do have to make sure you're loading the web page from the same web server as you're trying to connect to.

Comment: @DenisTsoi - `var socket = io()` on the client is all they need so there's no problem there.

Comment: @jfriend00 - oh i was just referring to the docs - i didn't know you could do that as shorthand

Comment: You have exactly the same problem as another question I answered yesterday.  I marked yours a dup of that and you can see the answer there.  You are creating two servers, starting only one of them and connecting socket.io to the one that was not started.